# How to get one colum from the join of 2 tables SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables like this:

Table1

```
id | name
------------------
1  | David
2  | Lucas
3  | Antonio
```

Table2

```
id | name
------------------
1  | Sergio
2  | Sergio
3  | Lucas
```

I want to select data to group duplicate records and return this:

```
name
------------------
David
Lucas
Antonio
Sergio
```

So I tried with this query

```
SELECT name FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 GROUP BY name
```

But nothing is returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `UNION` instead of `JOIN` :

```
SELECT name
FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT name
FROM table2;
```

`JOIN` is used for matching rows and produce subsequent columns from joined tables while `union` will combine all rows from two or more tables.

Answer (score 1):

use union

```
 select name fron table1
union
select name from table2
```